# EMR PySpark using Glue Catalog | Can not create a Path from an empty string;

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to show data using below spark sql :

```
spark.sql('select id,name,last_modified_dt,created_ts from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by created_ts desc ,last_modified_dt desc) as rnk from ( select * from pratik_test_staging.temp1 s union all select id,name,last_modified_dt,created_ts from pratik_test_temp.temp1)a)b where rnk = 1').show()
```

It is giving me output as :

[image]

But when I am trying to write it back to pratik_test_staging.temp1, it is throwing me error :

```
spark.sql('select id,name,last_modified_dt,created_ts from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by created_ts desc ,last_modified_dt desc) as rnk from ( select * from pratik_test_staging.temp1 s union all select id,name,last_modified_dt,created_ts from pratik_test_temp.temp1)a)b where rnk = 1').write.mode('overwrite').insertInto('pratik_test_staging.temp1',overwrite=True)
```

Error :
[image]

Note : 
1. I tried this with both ORC and Parquet and I am getting the same error with both file formats.
2. I am running Spark(EMR) using Glue catalog. Data is stored on S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify path. You can try this.

```
resultDf.write
      .option("path",outputPath)
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .saveAsTable(outputTableName)
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, i'll try.
Also, spark.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE SELECT * FROM TABLE") throwing the same error.